# How can I create a pipeline in Azure DevOps that uses an external git repo and a personal authentication token

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to create a new pipeline in azure DevOps. my git repo is an external one that uses a two factor authentication so I created a PAT for it. when I tried to import my repo using the PAT it works fine but I could not find a way to do the same when creating a new pipeline. is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

In the Add Pipeline screen, choose Generic Git:

[image]

Add the clone url and token in the Add Connection screen:

[image]

Comment: I tried this but when running the pipeline I see authentication failed when trying to fetch the repo

Comment: It runs a git command to do the clone. What happens when you locally run the same commands? You an grab them from the logs.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I create a pipeline in Azure DevOps that uses an external git repo and a personal authentication token

To resolve this issue, you can follow my test steps and check if it helps you.

As test I use the Github as an external git repo, and [create a personal authentication token on Github](https://help.github.com/en/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line).

Next, I go to **Project Settings**->**Service connections**->Add New Service connections->Other Git:

[image]

**Note:** If you attempt to access this Git repos to resolve refs and commit details in the pipeline, you need select the checkbox `Attempt sccessing this Git server from Azure Pipeline`.

Then, we could select this connection when we create new pipeline:

[image]

As test on my side, it works fine. If it not help you, please share how did you fetch the repo? A sample will be better.

Hope this helps.